# What is the minimum version of Xcode I can use for submission to app store (as of 2015 October)

Tags: ios

I have an app on the appstore currently that is built using Xcode 6.2 with a deployment target of iOS 8. The recent release Xcode 7, however only works on OSX 10.10

Can I submit updates to the app store(on 2015 October) by building on an earlier version of Xcode (6.2 in my case) because I am unable to update OSX to 10.10? Does Apple release documentation about this when it releases a new Xcode version? The only thing I found was this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1806/_index.html

which says that I should aim to build with the latest version of Xcode but does not mention if the app would be rejected/approved if built with a lower version.

Can anybody help me to get a confirmation regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with your update, Apple will not reject the App.
Make sure you keep Deployment Target as iOS 8 or less.

Risk is your App may get crashed on User devices with iOS 9 as its not been tested and compiled with iOS 9/Xcode 7.